# Maple, defining recursive relations

Tags: recursion, maple

I am slightly new to maple and have the following programming problem. I want to program the following recursive relations to maple.

```
i_{4n}=i_n,

i_{4n+1}=i_{2n}

i_{4n+2}=-i_{2n}

i_{4n+3}=i_n.

$i_0=1$.
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a Code-For-You-Service. Take a [TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before ask new questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy in Maple---probably easier than it was to ask this Question. I'll use **Ii** as the procedure name because I'm loathe to use such a common variable name as **i** for a procedure.

```
Ii:= proc(n::nonnegint)
option remember;
local q,r;
     q:= iquo(n,4,'r'); #integer quotient and remainder
     `if`(r=0 or r=3, thisproc(q), (-1)^(r-1)*thisproc(2*q))
end proc:

Ii(0):= 1: #Set initial value.
```

Comment: Well, did the above work for you? I told you before that I don't like it when you don't respond to my Answers.